# Issue in YAMEL file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-synapse

I am using Azure DevOps to Build and deploy my `Azure Synapse`

I have two `YAML` files. First one works well and I need to separate Build and Release steps. because of that I wrote second `YAML` file. Second `YAML` file has this error :

```
##[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern 
d:\a\1\s\SQL_ASynapse\bin\Release\SQL_ASynapse.dacpacCheck out how to troubleshoot failures at 
https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
```

First YAML file that works well:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
    solution: '**/*.sln'
    buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: AzureKeyVault@1
    inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXX'
    KeyVaultName: 'XXX-Dev'
    SecretsFilter: '*'

- task: VSBuild@1
    inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
    inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: SqlAzureDataWarehouseDacpacDeployment@1
    inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'XXX'
    AuthenticationType: 'server'
    ServerName: 'XXX'
    DataWarehouse: '$(SynapseName)'
    SqlUsername: '$(SynapseSQLUsername)'
    SqlPassword: '$(SynapseSQLPassword)'
    deployType: 'DacpacTask'
    DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
    DacpacFile: 'SQL_ASynapse\bin\Release\SQL_ASynapse.dacpac'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

Second YAML file who has error:

```
trigger:
- master

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:  
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

    - task: VSBuild@1
      inputs:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

    - task: VSTest@2
      inputs:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()

  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 'development'
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureKeyVault@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'XXX-Dev'
              KeyVaultName: 'XXX-Dev'
              SecretsFilter: '*'

          - task: SqlAzureDataWarehouseDacpacDeployment@1
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'XXX-Dev'
              AuthenticationType: 'server'
              ServerName: 'XXX'
              DataWarehouse: '$(SynapseName)'
              SqlUsername: '$(SynapseSQLUsername)'
              SqlPassword: '$(SynapseSQLPassword)'
              deployType: 'DacpacTask'
              DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
              DacpacFile: 'SQL_ASynapse\bin\Release\SQL_ASynapse.dacpac'
              IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

**UPDATE #1 FOR @Levi Lu-MSFT ANSWER**

I have changed my second script like below code :

```
...
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
- publish: $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\SQL_ASynapse\bin\Release ## path to a file or folder
  artifact: MyBuildOutputs
...

      - download: current  # refers to artifacts published by current pipeline
        artifact: MyBuildOutputs

      - task: SqlAzureDataWarehouseDacpacDeployment@1
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'xxx-Dev'
          AuthenticationType: 'server'
          ServerName: 'xxx.database.windows.net'
          DataWarehouse: '$(SynapseName)'
          SqlUsername: '$(SynapseSQLUsername)'
          SqlPassword: '$(SynapseSQLPassword)'
          deployType: 'DacpacTask'
          DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
          DacpacFile: 'SQL_ASynapse\bin\Release\SQL_ASynapse.dacpac'
          IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

But I have still same error.

Upload task result
[image]

Download task result
[image]

SqlAzureDataWarehouseDacpacDeployment error :

##[error]No files were found to deploy with search pattern 
   d:\a\1\s\SQL_ASynapse\bin\Release\SQL_ASynapse.dacpacCheck out how to 
   troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Microsoft-hosted agent. Every job defined in the yaml pipeline will run on a fresh new virtual machine. The virtual machine is discarded after one use.

So that the build artifacts from Build job of Build stage doesnot exist on the agent machine of the deploy job of Deploy stage. That's why you got above error.

You need to add a [publish task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#publish) after Vsbuild task in Build job to publish the build results to azure devops server. You should specify the correct path(where the build artifacts reside) to publish.

```
- publish: $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)\SQL_ASynapse\bin\Release ## path to a file or folder
  artifact: MyBuildOutputs
```

Then add a [download task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#download) before qlAzureDataWarehouseDacpacDeployment task in Deploy job to download the build results to deploy job agent. So that the build results will be available to the deployment tasks.

```
- download: current  # refers to artifacts published by current pipeline
  artifact: MyBuildOutputs
```

To publish and download build artifacts, You can also use [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops), [Download Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops).

**Update:**

When you use **download** task: See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#downloading-artifacts) for more information.

> By default, files are downloaded to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/{artifact}`, where artifact is the name of the artifact. The folder structure of the artifact is always preserved.

And you can see from above updated screenshot. The artifacts is downloaded to folder `D:\a\1\MyBuildOutputs`

[image]

So you should set **DacpacFile** attribute as below:

`DacpacFile : $(Pipeline.Workspace)/MyBuildOutputs/SQL_ASynapse.dacpac`

Comment: By clicking on that error link "github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/…" i have this Message : The Azure SQL Database Deployment task does not support BACPAC. Please send us feedback for the task and for the support for BACPAC and SQL scripts at RM_Customer_Queries at microsoft dot com.

Comment: Hi @ArdalanShahgholi By default, download task will download the files to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/{artifact}` (which you saw `D:\a\1/MyBuildOutputs` in above updated screenshot). So you need to set the `DacpacFile` attribute to `$(Pipeline.Workspace)/MyBuildOutputs/SQL_ASynapse.dacpac`.I updated above answer.